# Full-Screen Video iOs Devices

Tags: html, iphone, video

I am trying to make the video in my website full screen but viewing it on iphone it redirect me to the video, is there a way play the video on same page?

```html
<video poster="poster.jpg" preload autoplay loop>
            <source src="vimeo.mp4" type="video/mp4">
            To get the best experience of this website please consider <a href="https://browser-update.org/update.html">updating your web browser</a>
        </video>
```

~

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```html
<video <video poster="poster.jpg" preload autoplay loop playsinline>
            <source src="vimeo.mp4" type="video/mp4">
            To get the best experience of this website please consider <a href="https://browser-update.org/update.html">updating your web browser</a>
        </video>
```

you can simply add the "playsinline" attribute in the video tag, you may also include "webkit-playsinline"